# How to get current instance in class?

Tags: python, class, object, instance

I can't figure out how to get current instance in class.

```
class Basic(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def current_ins(self):
        ???
```

Is there any way to fetch current instance with `val` in python?
Thanks.

Comment: `self` is the currunt instance

Comment: How stupid of me.. Thanks, it solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self is the current instance of all the class. In your case,

```
class Basic(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def current_ins(self):
        #???
        print self.val    # one can use self to access all the member of it's class.
```

Answer (score 6):

The "current instance" is `self`.